# SSRS - Changing Horizontal striplines

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to add striplines based on values from a dataset. I have no problem showing the striplines but the problem I'm facing is that the striplines don't change with the values. Basically the strip lines are shown using only the first row of results from the dataset. When actually the values are the same for 1 - 12 points then change to another value for another 1 - 12 points and so on and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you could please provide an example or a screenshot of what is rendering compared to what you're looking to render that might help, that or at least some values in the dataset to look at.